# Running Power Platform / Selenium automated tests on build agent gives error "session not created"

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, power-platform

We are investigating executing Power Platform automated tests in our Azure DevOps pipeline.

The tests run and pass successfully when we run them from within a Power Platform session.

However, when we run them in a pipeline (meaning they get executed on a Windows Build Agent that we've created) we get the error below.

The framework uses Selenium as part of the test execution stack.

Has anyone else experienced this and resolved it?

```
  Error Message:
   Test method Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Tests.TestAutomation.RunTestAutomation threw exception: 
System.InvalidOperationException: session not created
from disconnected: Unable to receive message from renderer
  (Session info: chrome=99.0.4844.51) (SessionNotCreated)
  Stack Trace:
      at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeDriverService service, ChromeOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
   at Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Browser.BrowserDriverFactory.CreateWebDriver(BrowserOptions options) in C:\agent\_work\4\s\test\sdk\PowerAppsTestAutomation\Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Browser\BrowserDriverFactory.cs:line 25
   at Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Browser.InteractiveBrowser.get_Driver() in C:\agent\_work\4\s\test\sdk\PowerAppsTestAutomation\Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Browser\InteractiveBrowser.cs:line 85
   at Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Browser.BrowserPage.Execute[TResult](BrowserCommandOptions options, Func`2 delegate) in C:\agent\_work\4\s\test\sdk\PowerAppsTestAutomation\Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Browser\BrowserPage.cs:line 182
   at Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Api.TestAutomation.GetTestURLs(String filePath) in C:\agent\_work\4\s\test\sdk\PowerAppsTestAutomation\Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Api\Pages\TestAutomation.cs:line 52
   at Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Tests.TestAutomation.RunTestAutomation() in C:\agent\_work\4\s\test\sdk\PowerAppsTestAutomation\Microsoft.PowerApps.TestAutomation.Tests\TestAutomation\RunTestAutomation.cs:line 68
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the answer ourselves after deleting and re-installing both Chrome browser and chromedriver.

They have to be at precisely the same version, ours were slightly out.

Once we installed chromedriver and Chrome browser at version 99.0.4844.51, this problem went away.